# show phone activities below my app's page in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want that once my app runs; obviously there would be a transparent page; I want that all phone activities run below my app's page! e-g user runs app. now user can use phone menus but it should be below my app's page.

Comment: That's not how it works. Either they are running your app or doing something else. Windows is effectively a single app ecosystem.

Comment: cannot we use something like system notification like android ?

Comment: You want to basically add something over the top of everything the user does, correct? If that's the case, no. You can do notifications, but they don't work that way either.

Comment: Yes, I want to add something over the top of everything the user does!

Comment: Then it is not possible. Is there a reason for this? Maybe there's a better way to go about what you're trying to do..

Comment: Actually, I want that user run my app then I wil show broken image so that user feels his screen broken :) and he may continue with this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47524/discussion-between-steveg89-and-zaheer-mehmood)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: what you want to do is not possible in the Windows Phone environment.

A possible alternative: I believe the closest you could come to achieve what you want to do is by using Toast Notifications. Toast Notifications appear at the top of the screen, notifying the user of an event. It appears briefly then goes away. If the user clicks on the toast notification he is taken to a page that you specified in the notification.

The code for a toast notification would look something like this:

```
var toast = new ShellToast();
toast.Title= "A Toast Notification";
toast.Content = "The content for the toast notification";
toast.NavigationUri= new Uri("/PageToGoToOnToastTap.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
toast.Show();
```

The code above would be triggered by a background process.

Comment: Given what they said they really wanted in a comment, the example wouldn't be close to their request unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, but that is why I said what he wanted was impossible, and gave an alternative. So, the correct answer is just that it is not possible, which I did state.

Comment: My point was that you're alternative isn't really viable at all, and your answer isn't improved by adding it.